# Magnolia problem with BaseVersionManager and publishing the page

Tags: java, magnolia

I'm not able to publish a page. I'm using Magnolia EE 5.7

When I tried to publish a page I got this error:

[image]

And this in the logs:

```
ERROR info.magnolia.cms.core.version.BaseVersionManager - failed to copy versionable node to version store, reverting all changes made in this session
catalina.out: javax.jcr.version.VersionException: Unable to perform operation. Node is checked-in.
```

I exported the page in other instance and there everything was working fine. Then I noticed we reached version 1.99:

[image]

Can that be the problem? Because the rest of the logs are from magnolia core libraries:

[image]

Also I tried to publish the page from JCR and got success message, but the page is still not published.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to perform operation. Node is checked-in.

Seems like one previous attempt to publish that page failed (for some other reason) and that is preventing you from publishing now.

I guess you need to revert check-in op to allow node to be published again. If it's enterprise version, there might be something in tools to help you with that or you can open support ticket.
If you are using community version, you would need to find the node and via groovy or some other code revert check-in to re-enable publishing.